# Setting environment variables when running Scala / SBT test suite

Tags: scala, sbt, scalatest

I've created a Config object with a get method to return different strings based on the `PROJECT_ENV` environment variable.  If `PROJECT_ENV=test`, then `Config.get("somePath")` returns some/path.csv, otherwise it returns s3a://some_bucket/a_file.csv.

```
object Config {

  def test(): Map[String,String] = {
    Map(
      "somePath" -> "some/path.csv"
    )
  }

  def default(): Map[String,String] = {
    Map(
      "somePath" -> "s3a://some_bucket/a_file.csv"
    )
  }

  def get(key: String, env: Option[String] = sys.env.get("PROJECT_ENV")): String = {
    val lookupMap = if (env == Some("test")) {
      List(default(), test()).flatten.toMap
    } else {
      default()
    }
    lookupMap(key)
  }

}
```

With Ruby / RSpec, I set the environment variable in the `spec_helper.rb` file with `ENV['PROJECT_ENV'] = 'test'`.

What is the scalatest equivalent of the `spec_helper.rb` file?  How can I set an environment variable in Scala?  [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18411478/how-to-set-environmental-variable-from-scala) isn't sufficient.

My test suite runs successfully if I run `$ PROJECT_ENV=test sbt test`, but I want to simply run `$ sbt test`.

Comment: Why do you want to set environment variables inside sbt? Do you want to use it across applications?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This question appears to have overlap with [Set default env variable for test configuration in sbt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37330416/set-default-env-variable-for-test-configuration-in-sbt) .

The accepted answer over there worked well for me:

```
fork in Test := true
envVars in Test := Map("PROJECT_ENV" -> "test")
```

The key is to make sure to include the fork otherwise the same env in play when launching sbt gets used.

Answer (score 8):

I don't have enough reputation to post this as a comment for [Evan Closson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/699243/evan-closson)'s answer, but
[starting in SBT 1.10](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Migrating-from-sbt-013x.html#Migrating+to+slash+syntax) "the syntax for scoping keys has been unified for both the shell and the build definitions to the slash syntax."

So the answer becomes

```
Test / fork := true
Test / envVars := Map("PROJECT_ENV" -> "test")
```